# Changing scalar function in SQL Server not possible when it is default value of a column?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server does not allow changing a function that has been defined as a default value of a table column. I had to remove it as a default value, change it and reassign it to the column. I expected the default binding to be a reference to the function.

Does anyone know why it is not allowed to directly change such a function?

Comment: Because that's how Microsoft designed it. One likely reason is that changing the function could introduce a breaking change. Forcing you to remove the `DEFAULT` means that you can't break it; not without extra (possibly foolish) steps.

Comment: For starters, the function must take no parameters (or have all of its parameters supplied) and return a compatible type, so the engine would (at the very least) need to undertake special action when it sees the function is being used as a default somewhere (it might be multiple columns) to verify the changes are legal, and take out extra metadata locks/waits to ensure the default is not altered mid-transaction of any operation anywhere. This is quite a bit of work that probably didn't make the bar. You could always [ask for improvement](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).